# How to add content to the HEAD tag on dashboard/wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add some content (actually some scripts) to the wp-admin pages, so it will run on the media page, on posts page and all the other pages on the dashboard.

So I added this to the `functions.php`

```
function test() {
    // Your PHP goes here
    echo 'hello';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'test' );
```

But nothing happens. I also tried this wp enqueue script, but nothing seems to happen. I only need this on the dashboard.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

For script

```
function my_enqueue() {
      // your script
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue');
```

**FOR PHP**

```
function add_php_data() {

    // Do some stuff.

}

add_filter('admin_head', 'add_php_data');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want add custom meta tag in wp-admin head tag follow this procedure:

1. Go to *your-root-directory*/wp-admin/**admin-header.php**;
2. Open **admin-header.php** with a HTML Editor;
3. Search this row:

**`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">`**

4. Paste your meta code **after** row 87;
5. Save your file.

[Screenshot - view this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG4rO.png)

Comment: Do no do this. You don't want to edit php files for this to work. It will be broken with an update. You have hooks and functions to do this properly like suggested in other answer.

Comment: You can install a plugin but I don't like that solution.

Comment: It is not abut liking the solution. It is about it being wrong.

Comment: In my case this work good, if you've problem it's not my fault.

Comment: It is not always about the fact that something works or not. It is about future maintainability and ability for other developers to get around code easily.